# Australian Citizen on ESTA VISa

Tags: visas, esta

I am traveling with esta visa ( visa waiver program) i wanted to spend whole summer in North America. I was in US for 87 days and now came to Canada to see my family. I wasnt aware that Canada is under the 90 days for visa waiver!! I dont get it , I had to come to Canada with a  E-Visa. I am confused did I over stayed my US ESTA visa !! If i am whats should I do next to get my visa back ... As my return flight is from LA

Comment: How much time do you want to spend in the US before you return to Australia?  How long will you have been in Canada?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, **you're still fine**.  US rules apply in the US only, Canada doesn't care about US visa rules, all good.

Your problem will be **going back to the US**, even in transit, because you are still in an "adjacent territory" and that does not reset the 90-day clock.  I would advise you to either reroute your travel via Canada (there are direct Vancouver-Sydney flights), or go somewhere in Central/South America (Mexico does *not* count) to reset your clock before returning to the US.

Another option would be to apply for a regular US B1/2 or transit visa: this will almost certainly be granted, and the VWP limits would not apply anymore.

Also, terminology check: the program that lets you visit the US (and nearby countries) for 90 days is the Visa Waiver Program (VWP).  ESTA is the pre-approval that lets you travel to the US.